# Implement same Generic Interface 2 times with different Generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I had to implement 2 interface same time with different generic parameter as below. I get confused enough about it. I had no idea which one of them iterate itself in foreach. Now i understand first one is implicitly choosen.

I have tried `new BarList().GetEnumerator()` but i can not specify type parameter on method level.

Only solution i have found it that casting it to interface like(`new BarList() as IEnumerable<string>`)

After confusing about it enough. I just wanted to know that this design is not really good idea ? I have to avoid to implement same generic interface one more time ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var item in new BarList())
        {

        }
    }
}

class BarList: IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<int>
{

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

### **Edit:**

Let me explain why i am going in this way.

I had to Implement `IPagedList<T>` interface which is inherited from `IList<T>`. I wanted to write extension method which convert it to My view model. like below

`GetAll().ToPagedList(pageindex)`;//which is returning IPagedList Then i wanted to use it like below;

```
GetAll().ToPagedList(pageindex).ToViewModel<T,TViewModel>();
```

For achieve this I tried to return `IPagedList<ViewModel>` by that extension method.In that case I have to implement IPagedList 2 times with different parameter. But this strategy made confusing things. This is reason of it.

Comment: Can you post a link/code for IPagedList<T> or PagedList<T>?

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit confusing.  Why not make it explicit what is happening by adding the enumerators as properties rather than implementing them on the class.  For example,

```
class ProductCollection 
{
   public IEnumerable<int> EnumerateTheInts { get { //code to produce enumerator }}
   public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateTheStringss { get { //code to produce enumerator }}
}
```

It isn't always bad to implement an open generic interface twice on an object.  For example, IHandle could be implemented by a class which can handle two types of T.  However, I would find it confusing to implement IEnumerable twice, because you might not enumerate the type you expect in a for-each or in LINQ.  Same reasoning for implementing more than one indexer incidentally.  The type of your indexer will determine your result, which I can testify to being extremely confusing!

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is picking the `IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator` method by following the rules in 8.8.4 of the C# language specification which *first* looks for an accessible `GetEnumerator()` method on the `BarList` type. The only one of those which is available is the one returning `IEnumerator<int>`.

If you had made *that* method use explicit interface implementation as well, then it would have gone onto the later stages of section 8.8.4, which states that if there is more than one type T such that there is an implicit conversion from the expression type (`BarList` here) to `IEnumerable<T>` then an error is produced.

I would say this *is* a confusing design - I would probably add properties or methods to retrieve appropriate "views" on the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid it. However, it depends on your usage.

It will be okay if you just wanted to pass the instance into a function that expects a `IEnumerable<string>` parameter explicitely:

- you won't have to cast
- the function won't even '*see*' the other interfaces implemented, so there isn't any confusion.

YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Your current design is confusing. While you have not provided any information about the nature of the collection itself, from the name, I can assume you are supposed to iterate over a bunch of products. Perhaps, you should simply have a class of type `Product` with a `string` property and an `int` property and simply return an `IEnumerable<Product>` instead.

This way, with LINQ extension methods, you can compose the `IEnumerable<T>` object you actually mean with:

```
collection.Select(product => product.IntegerProperty)
collection.Select(product => product.StringProperty)
```

Of course, you can provide helper methods inside the object as well:

```
class ProductCollection : IEnumerable<Product> {
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetEnumerator() {
       // ... return Product objects here.
    }
    public IEnumerable<int> AsIntegerCollection() {
       // yield the integer collection here
    }
    public IEnumerable<string> AsStringCollection() {
       // yield the string collection here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are these collections of string and ints? I suppose they mean something in relation with the Product (for example Name, Id, etc...) so I would rather do something like this:

```
class ProductCollection : IEnumerable<Product>
{
    public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator()
    {
       ...
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> ProductNames // a helper to enumerate product names
    {
       ...
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> ProductIds // a helper to enumerate product ids
    {
       ...
    }
}
```