# Error CS1061 when calling LINQ-extension on class implementing additional IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, interface, extension-methods

I need to implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime,double>>>>` on a class that already derives from `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<DateTime,double>>`
Unfortunately, the compiler gets confused when I try to access LINQ extensions like `Any()` and returns a CS1061:

```
public interface MyInterface
    : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>>>>
{            
}

public class MyClass : Dictionary<int,Dictionary<DateTime, double>>, MyInterface            
{            
    //setting GetEnumerator() to public yields an CS0106
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>>>> 
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>>>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield break;
    }

    static public void Foo(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>>>> data)
    {
        //processing data...
    }            

    static void Demo()
    { 
        var mc = new MyClass();
        //stops working if MyInterface is implemented:
        mc.Any();//CS1061
        Foo(mc);
    }

    //Workaround for specific LINQ-extensions:
    //public bool Any() => this.Any();
}
```

At the end of the day, the class is used as parameter in methods like
`Foo(...)` which is required to be more general than `Dictionary`.

How can we use LINQ on `MyClass` while also implementing `MyInterface`?
(providing another approach to pass `MyClass` to `Foo` would also be helpfull, however it would not be the answer to the question).

the answer on a very similar question ([LINQ gets confused when implementing IEnumerable<T> twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878427/linq-gets-confused-when-implementing-ienumerablet-twice) - Case 2) does not satisfy the requirements. Since implementing `MyInterface` is required, I would need to wrap the baseclass and redirect all used Dictionary-methods - I would be happy to have a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why do you make us google CS1061? ("'type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).")

Comment: Jesus Christ your even talking about two different error codes with similar digits! (CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item)

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669140/1025555) explicit interface members cannot have modifiers. You need to cast `mc` to the explicitly implemented interface to access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your class implementes:

1. `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>>>>`
2. `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>>`

The compiler cannot infer which `Any` method you want to call, it needs you to help it make decisions, for instance, you want to call `Any` on the first interface:

```
mc.Any<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>>>>();
```

Comment: I would expect "type arguments for method 'Any' cannot be inferred from the usage" or "The call is ambiguous between the following methods" though. The actually produced compiler error seems wrong.

Comment: indeed, I let the compiler confuse me. I was aware of the ambiguity but was knocking at the wrong door. also ((MyInterface)mc).Any() is working. Thanks!